# How to specify a link or function to each angular tree-root node's children?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, tree, nodes

How do I specify a link or function to each angular tree-root node's children?

Example of .html

```
<!-- edited after advise from @SachilaRanawaka, 
 somehow (onToggle) is not having any reactions
 but (click) has-->

<tree-root #tree [nodes]="nodes" (click)="handleEvent($event)"></tree-root>
```

Example of .ts

```
nodes = [{id:1,name:"parent",children:[{id:2,name:"children1"},
                                       {id:3,name:"children2"}]
        }];

// edited after advise from @SachilaRanawaka
handleEvent(event){
   alert(event.eventName);
}
```

How do I specify a link (e.g. *a href*? *router*?) or function to run on clicking children1 or children2?

Is there a property for it?

Something along the line of this:

```
nodes = [{id:1,name:"parent",children:[
                                 {id:2,name:"children1", link:"/test/children1.html" },                                           
                                 {id:3,name:"children2", link:"/test/children2.html" }
                             ]
         }];
```

Here's a link regarding the kind of tree i'm using : [Angular 2 Tree](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/)

Comment: What is `<tree-root>`? If this is your custom component, how could we know if there is a property? What should the link or function do?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , apologies, I have included a link to the angular2 tree I was referring to.

Comment: can't you use a event to call function https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/events#activate

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka , hmm, that sounds interesting..does that only deals with the children?

Comment: I think it works for all nodes

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka , so in my case, let's say I want to do a function example "alert("event: "+ $event); " after clicking any of the child, which event should I use? onToggle or onFocus?

Comment: use `onToggle` to trigger your function.

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka , 1 more thing, is there anyway I can retrieve the node from the specified event? e.g.( alert("event node name: "+$event.getNode.getName());   )

Comment: use `$event.eventName`

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka , I tried ("event node name: "+$event.eventName());) but keep getting "event node name: undefined" though..

Is there anything i need to set on the <tree-node> tags?

Comment: can you create a demo (plnkr )

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka , I've edited the main question on top with the edits I did after heeding ur advices, can you take a look please. Thank you so much.

Comment: use `onToggle` instead of click, `(onToggle )="handleEvent($event)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've found a solution for my above question.

So just to share. Here goes...

The idea of this is to get the name of the node with no children and do something with it. Making it clickable.

As usually the clickable node should be the last expanded node.

For my example below, I gave it a function to call an alert with the node name.

**updated .HTML to use ng-template**

```
<tree-root #tree [nodes]="nodes">
 <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node>
   <!--For node with no children(last node), give it a function/link-->
   <div *ngIf="!node.data.children">
     <span (click)="doSomething(node.data.name)">{{ node.data.name }}</span>
   </div>
   <!--For node with children, don't need a link, all it needs to do is to just expand-->
   <div *ngIf="node.data.children">
     <span>{{ node.data.name }}</span>
   </div>
 </ng-template>
</tree-root>
```

**add doSomething(name) method to .ts**

```
    nodes = [{id:1,name:"parent",children:[
                                     {id:2,name:"children1"},                                           
                                     {id:3,name:"children2"}
                                 ]
             }];

    doSomething(nodeName){
       alert(nodeName);
    }
```

So output:

```
 > parent               <--- not clickable
    > children1        <--- clickable and generated alert box
    > children2        <--- clickable and generated alert box
```